# Populating Field value with javascript resulting data not saved

Tags: plugins, craft4

trying to make an event that populating Text into Doxter Field when certain field is change, But on success populating there is weird saving behaviour occurs,

- if we save entry by using [Save Button](https://easyimg.io/i?url=5jkpwqo9o&name=screenshot_2024-02-29_at_10.58.58_am.png) the populated text is not getting saved.
- But if we try to save it using [Save and continue editing](https://easyimg.io/i/j634c5fxq/screenshot_2024-02-29_at_11.03.21_am.png) the populated text is getting saved.

if you want to recreate this behaviour, make:

- create field that will be use to trigger populate text into Doxter Field
- create Doxter field
- Try this Event

```
Event::on(
    Elements::class,
    Elements::EVENT_BEFORE_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    function(ElementEvent $event){
        $element = $event->element;
        $view = Craft::$app->getView();
        $view->registerAssetBundle(PopulateFieldAsset::class);
    
        if ($element->isFieldModified('your field to trigger populate', false) && ElementHelper::isDraft($element)) {
            $content = "Your String"
            $view->registerJs("new InsertValue().init({$content});");
    
            return ;
        }
);
```

- use `Jquery('your doxter textarea Id').val()` to populate the value

Note : the actual code is more longer than the code above this is just general idea, currently i found the solution by using `setFieldValue`. i just curious of the saving behaviour whether this from Craft CMS, Doxter PLugin or Event that i use :)